# Несовместимая версия hibernate и GlassFish

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, glassfish

Есть проект с такими зависимостями

pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

xml

```
<persistence-unit name="DEVMODE" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/devcolibri</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

после деплоя проекта на http://localhost:4848/, вылетает ошибка

Exception while preparing the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.

я посмотрел - это ошибка не совместимости версий. У меня стоит 5 сервер glassFish. Какие зависимости нужно прописать для hibernate?

Comment: Это не ошибка несовметимости версий, это значит, что кто-то в рантайме пытается загрузить класс, который не лежит в classpath, через `Class.forName()`. Соответственно конечная задача - сделать так, чтобы этот класс там оказался.

Comment: я правильно понял что у меня отсутствует переменная среды classpath?

Comment: Нет, у вас отсутствует нужный класс в тех местах (скорее всего, в `lib/` или конечном jar/war), из которых JVM грузит классы.